# How many unique items from two or more peeks of N elements

Tags: probability

First of all, excuse me if this is a duplicate question, I don't know exact english math terms and I wasn't able to find a duplicate. Also excuse me if I don't use the right terms while describing the question.

Let's say I have N items.

Now, I take $k_1$ items and then I put them back.

Again I take $k_2$ items and I put them back.

This repeats for a number of times.

Given that the total number of items, the count of peeks and the number of items taken on each peek are known, but not the items taken, on average, how many unique items will I have taken?

For example if my set is $[1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 8]$:

1. I take $[3\ 5\ 8]$
2. I take $[1\ 4\ 5\ 7]$
3. I take $[2\ 7\ 8]$

The unique items are $[1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 7\ 8]$ with 5, 7 and 8 repeating twice. So I have 7 elements out of 8.

Now I would like to know if a formula exists with much larger N and $k_m$

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want a formula for the expected value of the number of items that are taken at least once. Is that a correct interpretation of your question?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your example. How do you get $9$ in your second and third samples, if the numbers in your set only go up to $8$?>

Comment: Ooops... true... that's a typo. Fixing it!

Comment: @drhab I don't know the meaning of expected value, but that seems quite correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of items that are taken at least once, let $X_{i}=1$ if item $i$ is taken at least once and $X_{i}=0$
otherwise.

Then $P\left[X_{i}=0\right]=\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left(1-\frac{k_{j}}{N}\right)$
and $\mathbb{E}X_{i}=P\left[X_{i}=1\right]=1-\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left(1-\frac{k_{j}}{N}\right)$

hence: $$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}=N\left(1-\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left(1-\frac{k_{j}}{N}\right)\right)$$

Comment: o.O that looks quite complex. May I ask you how did you get to it? Thanks again...

Comment: Also, that $j$ under the product should have been $i$ right?